# is it possible to search two fields with one passed in reference django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django rest framework project. I have a friend models which has a friender and friended model. the friender is a foreign key for the user which contains a username and friended is a char field that is going to be a username.

I have a username passed in through the url that calls the serialize. I want it to be used to search through both fields and see if any records contain username for friender and friended.

Would it be better to set both of the as charfields and store usernames in both or is there an easy way to seach both fields and combine the results...

right now it checks the friended... i want to to check friended and friender.username

here is my code:

models:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    friender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friended = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.friender.username + self.friended
```

serializer:

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = (
            'friender',
            'friended',
            'status',
            'blocked',
            'favorite',
        )
        depth=2
```

views:

```
from users.models import Friend
from ..serializers import FriendSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class FriendViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Friend.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'friended'
    serializer_class = FriendSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with simple OR queryset.  However, your friender and friended fields have to both be the same format.  So, pick either ForeignKey or CharField.  I would recommend ForeignKey and you would then just have to add a 'related_name' attribute to both, in order to avoid conflicts.  Something like the below.

```
friender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friender_user_id')
friended = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friended_user_id')
```

queryset would need a Q import:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Friend.objects.filter(Q(friender__name__iexact='John Doe') | Q(friended__name__iexact='John Doe')
```

Comment: i made changes to the models. I am trying to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` but it isi not adding the tables to the database. do you know why it is not adding the tables to the database...